# Convert h264 to VFR mp4 with duplicated frames/timestamps

Tags: video-processing, video, video-compression

I have a `.h264` video file with a separate text file containing timestamps for each frame in `timestamp v2` format. Where the starting frame doesn't necessarily start with a timestamp value 0.

I want to containerize both files into a VFR `.mp4` container where the PTS frame values are populated from the timestamp text files.

I found this repo https://github.com/nu774/mp4fpsmod that supposedly solves this, but in my case, the timestamps are sometimes duplicated and two consecutive frames have the same PTS value. In this case `mp4fpsmod` hangs.

Is there another way to construct the .mp4 with duplicated timestamps? Or if I could somehow be able to drop the duplicated timestamps and corresponding frames in the h264 file.

I did manage to convert to a VPF .mkv file with [mkvmerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.external_timestamp_files), but I would need to show the video in a browser, which is not possible with an mkv.

Comment: Did you figured out a solution for your problem? I have kinda similar issue where I have VFR h264 bitstream and a way to corelate frames with timestamps outside of it and looking for similar solution ([my thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423556/is-it-possible-to-make-vfr-mp4-from-a-raw-h264-bitstream-using-ffmpeg))

Comment: @AdamSzmyd unfortunately no. The VFR isn't that important for the project I'm working on, so this segment is currently on hold. But did you try with the mp4fpsmod repo I referenced? There you can pass change the timestamps of a mp4 file by passing a text file with timestamps. It wasn't helpful to me, only because I had duplicate consecutive timestamps (non monotonic).